# Starting a fragment with Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a login page occupying first half of the screen containing fields like 2 `EditText` for email and password and `Button`. The second half contains a `ListFragment` with public projects. If the user successfully logs in, a new Activity should start containing the same `Fragment` of the MainActivity but withe different data - the user created projects. I have successfully made the MainActivity, but the next activity after the user logs in fails to start. The exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.amangrover.finalapp1/com.example.amangrover.finalapp1.ProjectListFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

private_projects_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.example.amangrover.finalapp1.ProjectListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/privateProjectFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ProjectListFragment.java:

```
public class ProjectListFragment extends ListFragment{
String[] projectTitle;
String[] projectImage;

CustomAdapter adapter;

private List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    projectTitle = args.getStringArray("projectTitle");
    projectImage = args.getStringArray("imageId");

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for(int i=0; i<projectTitle.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(projectTitle[i], 0);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

I am using CustomAdapter with this list. Although now I understand that `ProjectListFragment.java` is not an activity, so it can't start with intents. So how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Just `attach` and `remove` `Fragment` to your `Activity`.

Comment: Look at this example [http://java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/DemonstrationofusingListFragmenttoshowalistofitemsfromacannedarray.htm](http://java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/DemonstrationofusingListFragmenttoshowalistofitemsfromacannedarray.htm)

Comment: So I have to make a new `Activity` and `attach` the `ProjectListFragment` to that activity?

Comment: Ya. That's right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ProjectListFragment.java** is a fragment so u can't use intents to start a fragment transaction. The only solution i can think of is create a new Activity that has a **frame layout** in its layout acting as a fragment container.

Then using intent you can start that activity and in **onCreate** of that activity you can Show your Fragment using fragment transaction (Attach that fragment to your activity as fragments are a part on activity.The cannot be opened separately). So This way u can achieve what u want.

For more clear idea See [THIS EXAMPLE](http://ProjectListFragment.java%20is%20a%20fragment%20so%20u%20cant%20use%20intent) and [THIS EXAMPLE](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: So , I should make a new `Activity` and `attach` the `ProjectListFragment` to that activity ?

Comment: I tried it , and it is giving me an error , no view found for ProjectListFragment.java. It is really starting to confuse me. Can you please describe the solution in a bit more detail?

Comment: can you please describe the steps you followed.I've added the description links for you

Comment: Sorry , it was my mistake. I wasn't setting the content view in the new Activity I created to call the fragment. Now it is working fine. Thank You.Just want to ask 1 more ques though- how can I pass some data, say an array of strings from an activity to a fragment?

Comment: You can use bundle for that purpose.set the bundle in the arguments.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android